# Passing y contentOffset from scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView to another view controller using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift

I am new to programming and swift.

I have a mainViewController with a containerView which contains a scrollView. I would like to be able to pass the value of the y contentOffset from this scrollView ( from the scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView function) to update the frame.origin.y of a image in the mainViewController so that it moves inrelation to the containerView's scrollView.

How can i share data between the two View controllers (or multiple view controllers) using swift?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your scroll view is named **sView** and UIImageView is named **img**.
Then you should write something like this in your ViewController:

In class declaration add comma and scroll view delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
```

Then you should implement **scrollViewDidScroll** function somewhere after **viewDidLoad**

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView:UIScrollView){
    if scrollView == sView {
        let frame = CGRectMake(img.frame.origin.x, sView.contentOffset.y, img.frame.size.width, img.frame.size.height)
        img.frame = frame
        println("Just check if it's called")
    }}
```

After that add to **viewDidLoad**

```
    //You've aldeady declared sView and img 
    self.view.addSubview(sView)
    self.sView.delegate = self
```

Should work then :)